# Interacting pyqtgraph with command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial, pyqtgraph

Im trying to implement an interactive menu via the command prompt in python 3.X to plot serial data from an arduino using pyqtgraph. Ive read the documentation on Qt but i just cant get it to work. The objetive is that when the user send 'A' the plotting starts, and finally when he presses 'B' the plotting stops. I've tried to wrap the timer into an if statement but that wont do the trick, it pops the window and crash. Any help would be appreciate.

here the code:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
import threading, serial, time


def main():
    while True:
        flag=input('Press A to start plotting, Press B to close the plotting sequence')
        if flag is 'A':
            #Start my plotting sequence
        elif flag is 'B'
            #Close my plotting sequence


app = QtGui.QApplication([])


win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
win.setWindowTitle('Datos de Arduino')

p1 = win.addPlot()
p1.setYRange(0, 5, padding=0)
curva1  = p1.plot()
datos   = [0.0]
data    = [0.0]
fdatos1 = [0.0]
y1 = np.zeros(1000, dtype=float)
raw = serial.Serial('COM6', 9600)
raw.close()
raw.open()
m = 0

def update():
    global curva1, curva2, curva3, m, y1, fdatos1
    with serial_lock:
        datos1 = raw.readline().decode('utf-8')
    #datos1 = datos.split(',')
    fdatos1[0]= float(datos1)
    y1[m] = fdatos1[0]

    if m == 999:
        y1 = np.zeros(1000, dtype=float)
        m = 0
    else:
        m += 1
    curva1.setData(y1)
    app.processEvents()


timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```